# know number of elements with vba scraping web

Tags: vba, web-scraping, classname, content-length

hello everyone I would like to know numer of elements like the following

```
<div id="datatable">
         <form id="theForm" name="theForm" >......</form>
          <div class="no_data_dd" id="no_data" >....
               <div class= ....>.....
                    <div class= ....> 
                    </div>
               </div>
         </div>
         <div class="score_row score_header">.../div>
         <div class="score_row match_line e_true" >..</div>
         <div class="score_row padded_date ">..</div>
         <div class= ....>.....</div>
</div>
```

I tried with

```
Set itemEle = objIE.document.getElementById("scoretable")
Length = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("class").Length
```

length = 0 and nont =5

why?

Comment: sorry it  is not table

Comment: `class` isn't an element, it's an *attribute*. `div` is the element there.

Comment: Try this `Set post = HTML.getElementById("datatable").getElementsByTagName("div"): MsgBox post.Length`. Here `HTML` being `New HTMLDocument`. It should give you 7 as result if you consider the above snippet.

Comment: thank you, but if I only wanted fathers without children?
I would like only the most external ones, that is 5 and not 7

Comment: father without children is not a father and all divs (bar 1) are siiting in the overarching div. You could show the specific result you are after and enough HTML to give some idea how robust any implementation we attempt might be.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try get "elements" by instead of get "element" that might be a reason for the answer

Comment: Please clarify your answer by adding code.